# CentOS:Cant use yum to install package

Tags: centos, vmware

I just installed Centos6 on VMware and i use NAT, but when i use yum i get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run a `service network restart` to see if your virtual machine will pick up DHCP information from its bridged interface. Then check your connection's status (The output of `ifconfig` would help).

Check the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` to make sure you have a DNS resolver listed. Otherwise, you won't be able to get to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

apparently he can not connect to the repo (couldn't resolve host...)
You will find these url in the file `.repo` in:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/
```

trying to see the file `CentOS-Base.repo` contained:

```
tail /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

and comment the line of the URL not found

More information of [yum maintenance](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-maintenance.html)

Comment: #mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releserver&arch-basesearch&repo=os baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releaserver/os/$basearch

Comment: you are sure to have an internet connection in your vm?

Comment: ok then, you must solve this problem of connection for use yum ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you cannot access the internet, more precisely the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to ~/.bashrc

export PATH="/sbin:$PATH"

Answer (score -1):

You can add two nameservers in your `/etc/resolv.config`. `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` work.